# Cartesian product set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say I have the set $A=\{1,2\}.$

Now if I take the cartesian product $2$ times (of $A$) I get

$$A\times A=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}.$$

We can see that half (2) of the sets have an even number of 1s

Now, how do I specify that I want all the sets for which there are an even number of $1$’s for the set $B=\{1,2\}^n.$

The size of the set B is = ${2^n}/2 = 2^{n-1}$

All the subsets minus all the subsets that do not have an even number of ones (i.e half)

Comment: What means the notation $\{1,2\}^n?$

Comment: {1,2} x {1,2} x ... x {1,2}

Comment: cartesian product n times

Comment: Precisely how many times (based on your thinking) does the number 1 appear in $A x A$?  Also, to avoid confusion, please detail what $A x A x A$ ends up being.  That is, if it is a set with 8 elements, what are these elements?  Further, at the start of your query you define $A = \{1,2\}.$  Then, near the end of your query you redefine $A$ as $\{1,2\}^n.$  This is not a good idea.

Comment: Are you looking for a collection of subsets of $B$ that contain an even number of $1$'s?

Comment: ................yep

Comment: Please edit your query to make it crystal clear.  That is, make it impossible for anyone to be unsure of what you are asking.  For example, please see my previous comment.

Comment: I'm not very sure by what you mean by subsets containing an even number of 1's. I've interpreted it as a subset whose combined total number of 1's iterated over each tuple is even.

Comment: "*We can see that the number of 1's that appear is 2*" I do not understand this sentence... I count four: $\{(\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{1}),(\color{green}{1},2),(2,\color{purple}{1}),(2,2)\}$, each colored differently (*the red $1$, blue $1$, green $1$, and purple $1$*).  From the comments and later text, surely you mean to say "*We can see that the number of* **times that** $1$ **appears an even number of times in the tuple** *is $2$*"... a very different sentence than the one that you wrote.  Also, these elements of the cartesian product ought to be referred to as tuples here, not sets.

Comment: Now... it is unclear why you are asking this question and what generalizations you hope to make from this... Is your primary goal counting the sizes of such sets?  Is your goal learning how to manipulate mathematical notation?  Are you hoping to generalize to $A$ containing more than just two numbers, any number of which being even or odd?  Are you hoping to generalize to cartesian products involving multiple different sets rather than just powers of the same set?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to write the collection you ask for as a direct product. I would personally just write

$$\big\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \{1,2\}^n : |\{i \in [1,n] : a_i = 1\}| \mbox{ is even}\big\}.$$

If you want something with fewer words, you could go with

$$\Big\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \{1,2\}^n : 2 \mid \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\Big\}.$$

Comment: It should be emphasized that while the first notation can be used for when $A$ is generalized further, the second notation took advantage of the fact that the only other non-$1$ element in $A$ happened to be even.  This second notation would not work the same in the event that $A$ were changed to have a non-$1$ odd number as well, such as if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ instead.

Comment: In the second equation, what does it mean after the :

Comment: Yes, the first approach is general, and the second is very specific to your case. It meas that 2 divides the sum $a_1 + \cdots + a_n$.

Comment: @user11015000 "*such that*".  It is [setbuilder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).  It reads in words "The set of tuples of the form $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ from the set $\{1,2\}^n$ such that $2$ divides the sum of terms in the tuple."

Comment: @user11015000 Moved response to that below your answer post

Answer (score 1):

$B=\{1,2\}^n$. Let $C\subseteq B$. Let $f:C\to\mathbb N$ such that
$$
f(c)=c_1+c_2+...+c_n,\text{where $c=(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)$}
$$
Define property
$$
p(C) \equiv_\text{def}\;\sum_{c\in C}f(c)=0\pmod 2
$$
You can specify the collection as $\mathcal B=\{C\subseteq B:p(C)\;\text{holds}\}$

Comment: I've interpreted "subset of $B$ containing an even number of $1$'s" as a subset whose combined total number of $1$'s iterated over each tuple is even.

Comment: This is good but it is too length, I dont think it should be this complicated

Comment: There could be more concise ways of specifying the collection but that won't necessarily mean it will be simple. I just used familiar set and function notations.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways,

$$\{(a,b)\in\{1,2\}:2|\#(a=1+b=1)\}\ ?$$